# Phonegap push notification is there a way to add up badge number?

Tags: ios, cordova

Is there a way in ios where you can take the last badge number and add it to the new badge number coming in from the push

The code for ios is here

```
- (void)setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {

    self.callbackId = command.callbackId;

    NSMutableDictionary* options = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    int badge = [[options objectForKey:@"badge"] intValue] ?: 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badge];

    [self successWithMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"app badge count set to %d", badge]];
}
```

This is the .js

```
// Call this to set the application icon badge
PushNotification.prototype.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber = function(successCallback, errorCallback, badge) {
    if (errorCallback == null) { errorCallback = function() {}}

    if (typeof errorCallback != "function")  {
        console.log("PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber failure: failure parameter not a function");
        return
    }

    if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
        console.log("PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
        return
    }

    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "PushPlugin", "setApplicationIconBadgeNumber", [{badge: badge}]);
};
```

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin source files

Comment: Steven, have you got the android setApplicationIconBadgeNumber to actually work??  For me it always returns an error: invalid action.

Comment: Sorry Eric, I haven't logged in for sometime. No i never ever did, so i just left it.

Comment: Eric, I experienced `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber` to return `invalid action` when I called on Android with phonegap-plugin-push v1.6.0 -- because the feature is not implemented in that version. I had to update phonegap-plugin-push to 1.8.2.